# Первый част кода работает а дальше нет. Не знаю почему. Python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! 
Пишу бот в телеграмме на python (первый раз). Первый часть кода работает а дальше нет. Даже нет ошибки. Как будто дальше нет ничего. Не знаю почему. Не знаю даже как заставит запускать остальное часть кода. Может какое то связка нужно между переменны. Может я что то упускаю. Пожалуйста помогите!!! Телеграм бот: @godevelopbot . Отправлю вес код: (сорий за плохой русского языка)

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
token = 'XXX:XXX'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как тебя зовут?')
  bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, hello)

def hello(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {name}. Рад тебя видеть. 
   Пожалуйста, отправте мне свой номер для этого есть команда 
   /geophone'.format(name=message.text))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['geophone'])
def geophone(message):
  keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, 
  one_time_keyboard=True)
button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить номер телефона", 
request_contact=True)
keyboard.add(button_phone)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Согласны ли вы предоставить ваш номер       
 телефона для регистрации в системе?", reply_markup=keyboard)
 # Вот до сюда всё работает а дальше нет.

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
if message.text == "Hamkorlarimiz✅":
    j = "@yurtboshim kanali - bu kanalda siz, prezidentimiz tomonidan 
    chiqarilayotgan farmonlar, farmoyishlar hamda rasmiy tashriflar haqida 
    xabardor bo'lasiz"
    v = "@yurtdoshim kanali - bu kanalda siz, yurtimizda va dunyoda ro'y 
    berayotgan xodisalar va yangiliklardan xabardor bo'lasiz."
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, j)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, v)

if message.text == "Pul ishlash":
    j = "'Pul ishlash' bo'timizning pul ishlash bo'limiga xush kelibsiz! Pul 
    ishlash uchun bu ssilkani  (ref ssilka) do'stlaringizga yuboring. Siz 
    yuborgan ssilka bo'yicha kirgan xar bitta do'stingiz uchun sizga 100 
    so'm miqdorida mablag' qo'shiladi. Demak, qancha ko'p do'stingizga 
    yuborsangiz shuncha ko'p pul ishlaysiz :)\n"
    v = "Ishlagan pullaringizni esa telefon raqamingizga paynet qildirish, 
    yoki bo'lmasam click plastik kartangizga tushurib olishingiz mumkin! 
    Nimani qarab turibsiz? Qani olg'a pul ishlang! Omadingizni bersin!\n"
    '''bot.send_message(message.chat.id, j)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, v)'''

    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False,row_width=3)
    user_markup.row("Mening hisobim", "Pullarimni olish","⏪Orqaga 
    qaytish!!!⏪")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, j,reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, v, reply_markup=user_markup)

if message.text == "Mening hisobim":
    j = "Hozirda sizning hisobingiz 0 sum."
    v = "Do'stlaringizni botimizga olib keling va hisobingizni ko'paytiring 
    :)"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,j)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,v)

if message.text == "Pullarimni olish":

    j = "Minimal pul yechib olish summasi 5.000 so'm."
    v = "Hisobingizni yechib olish uchun telefon raqamingizni kiriting:"
    d = "Misol uchun:"
    s = "+998901234562"
    k = "yoki"
    n = "8600 8765 5453 5895"
    l = "Raqam kiritishda yanglishmang :)"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, j)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, v)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, d)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, s)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, k)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, n)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, l)

if message.text == "⏪Orqaga qaytish!!!⏪":
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False,row_width=3)
    user_markup.row("Hamkorlarimiz✅", "Pul ishlash")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Asosiy 
    sahifa!!!!",reply_markup=user_markup)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: В публикуемых вопросах принято скрывать токены, логины и пароли, для безопасности

Comment: @DaemonHK, вот только редактирование сообщения не поможет скрыть утекший ключ — тут есть история правок. А ключ придётся отзывать и делать замену.

Comment: @mymedia ну хоть как нибудь (( Хотя ключ, да, придется менять по-любому

Comment: Token недействительный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я типо конечно не знаком с API Телеграма, но чисто концептуально насколько я понимаю, вы не установили handle_text как обработчик ответа на команду geophone, так как вы делали это для start в этой строке:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, hello)
```

Хоть там случай немного другой, ну да ладно.

P.S зря вы token спалили..

Comment: Лучше использовать [`Finite state machine`](https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html) так как `register_next_step_handler` не стабилен

Comment: Token недействительный